# The parameter 'address' cannot be an empty string

Tags: c#, windows, email, exception, gmail

I am trying to send an email c#, using the using System.Net.Mail;

However I am getting the following exception message:

> This is my send email code:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

smtpServer = new SmtpClient();
smtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

mail.From = new MailAddress("example@gmail.com");

mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(textBox7.Text));

mail.Subject = "Your User ID and Password For etc company";

mail.Body = "Your ID IS:" + textBox1.Text + "  Your Password Is: " + 
textBox2.Text;

smtpServer.Port = 587;

smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();

smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

smtpServer.Send(mail);

MessageBox.Show("Mail Successfully Sent To " + textBox7.Text, "Message", 

MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor `new MailAddress` does not accept an empty string. The issue is most likely that your `textBox7.Text` is an empty string.